# Unable to Add a new device to Apple Developer Member Program

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to add my new iPhone 6 as a test device in iOS Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles page in my Apple developer Member Program but I am unable to do so.

I have the Apple Developer License which I renewed recently. I do have a iphone 5 device added a year back and it was no problem to add it then.

But now when I am trying to add a new device, after I enter the device UDID(obtained from XCode) and the device name, and hit 'Continue', the loading indicator just goes on and on. I have been trying to add a new device for the last 2 days with no success. Can anyone please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried just plugging the device into your Mac, running Xcode and deploying an app to it?  That is what I do with new devices and Xcode just works it all out for me.

Comment: Contact customer care ...

Comment: trying with different web browsers may help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Paulw11. Your solution solved my problem. Thanks to everyone else as well for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar problem like that once in chrome browser, then i had tried in safari browser and it had worked for me. Also try opening itunes connect site in incognito window.

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same problem in chrome the loading indicator just goes on and on. But it actually add a device in the list. In new tab open your registered device list and you can see your new registered device in the list.